# Set the width for drawLine using TextField

Tags: java, netbeans, textfield

How can I use the TextField to set the width of the line, 
            g.drawLine(oldx, oldy, evt.getX(),evt.getY());
I need to set an initial value, and then let the user change it through the TextField. 
Thanks

Comment: What language? What have you tried?

Comment: Why would you use a TextField? That is an AWT components. I would suggest you use Swing. If you do use Swing then I would use s JSpinner to get the value. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html). If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming you are using swing,*

Width of the line is set by [Graphics2D#setStroke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setStroke%28java.awt.Stroke%29) method.

```
g.setStroke(stroke);
```

Call this in the overridden `paintComponent` method.

---

The `stroke` can be initialized as

```
float width = 5f;    // Initial value.
stroke = new BasicStroke(width);
```

---

You should have `stroke` object as a member of your class in which `paintComponent` method is overridden.

Now you can update stroke object using the text field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have right now, but I have    width = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());    after that to read from user input. It doesn't work now

Comment: Have you put that code in a button's actionlistener or something? When is it being called? Posting some code might help understanding the situation better.